# $p$-adic Bott periodicity?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, p-adic-analysis, clifford-algebras, rigid-analytic-geometry

The Bott periodicity theorem can be formulated as the existence of homotopy equivalences $\Omega^2(KU)\equiv KU$ and $\Omega^8(KO)=KO$. I always wondered whether this theorem could also be transferred to the other completions of $Q$, i. e. the $p$-adic fields. Of course, since the topology of $\mathbb Q^p$ behaves rather incompatibly with the topology of, say, $CW$ complexes, it's not really clear how to make sense of that. (The classifying space of the topological group should have the same homotopy groups as the classifying space constructed from the underlying discrete group, if I'm not mistaken). Therefore a more sophisticated approach (possibly via $p$-adic rigid geometry) might be necessary. So, does there exist anything which could be considered as the $p$-adic analogue of Bott periodicity?

As I understood it, the underlying algebraic reason for the lengths of the period in the real and complex case, respectively) is that the sequence of Clifford algebras $Cl(k,n)$ exhibits the same periodicity behaviour up to Morita equivalence (precisely, $Cl(k+8,\mathbb R )=M(Cl(k,\mathbb R),8)$ and $Cl(k+2,\mathbb R )=M(Cl(k,\mathbb R),2)$. A quick check [in the literature](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AMBP/AMBP_1994__1_1/AMBP_1994__1_1_85_0/AMBP_1994__1_1_85_0.pdf) shows that the clifford algebras over $\mathbb Q_p$ are also periodic of length $2$ if $p\equiv 3 \mod 4$, $4$ if $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ and $8$ for $p=2$, so at least at this algebraic level, Bott periodicity is present.

Comment: Your statements of Bott periodicity are slightly off; you should replace $BU$ and $BO$ with $KU = \mathbb{Z} \times BU$ and $KO = \mathbb{Z} \times BO$ respectively. These are the complex and real K-theory spectra, and so one possible $p$-adic replacement for them is the algebraic K-theory spectrum of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (which completely ignores the $p$-adic topology). These are used by Dustin Clausen (http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5851), for example, to give a $p$-adic J-homomorphism.

Comment: Also, I think the $\Omega_8$ statement is much cooler as two $\Omega_4$ statements, going between $KO$ and $KSp$.

Comment: Just to add something on the notation to the comment of  @QiaochuYuan. I think as $\Omega$ sees only based maps, then you have $\Omega^8BO=\Omega^8(BO\times\mathbb{Z})=BO\times\mathbb{Z}$. The equality $KO=\mathbb{Z}\times BO$ seems to equate a spectrum with a space which I don't understand. 
The part of your comment on the isomorphism of homologies of $BG$ and $BG^\delta$ where $G^\delta$ is $G$ when equipped with discrete topology, is Milnor's conjecture, and I am not sure to what extent is has been verified. Amrani has a recent work on it available at http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06101v2.pdf.

Comment: I have never tried to do the proof of the periodicity theorems on my own, but if something like what you look for holds, then I suppose one can detect new finite families of elements in stable homotopy of spheres; you can use Bott periodicity to prove Adams Hopf invariant one result...

Comment: @user51223: I'm being a bit imprecise; when I want to think of a spectrum as a space I take its zeroth space. I don't understand what your comment about Milnor's conjecture is referring to.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  Dominik writes
``The classifying space of the topological group should have the same homotopy groups as the classifying space constructed from the underlying discrete group, if I'm not mistaken.'' I presume he is suggesting that the map $BG^\delta\to BG$ is a homotopy equivalence.  That the map above induces an isomorphism in homology was Milnor conjecture, and the suggestion of Dominik is much stronger I suppose; I don't know how a CW-complex structure for $BG^\delta$ can be derived if one for $BG$ is known so that one can apply Whitehead Theorem to Milnor's conjecture.

Comment: If one had Milnor conjecture, as Amrani has proven, then together with Whitehead Theorem in presence of a nice CW- structure, the above statement on the map $BG^\delta\to BG$ being s homotopy equivalence would be correct.

Comment: People generally call it the Friedlander-Milnor conjecture to distinguish it from other conjectures of Milnor. It is only for homology with finite coefficients and is false for rational coefficients. Suslin proved the relevant cases $G=U(\infty),O(\infty),Sp(\infty)$ using his rigidity theorem.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: it should be noted that the algebraic K-theory spectrum of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not periodic which follows from the localization sequence and the finite field case.

Comment: @user51223: the Friedlander-Milnor conjecture is a statement about algebraically closed fields (and of course finite coefficients as pointed out by Ben Wieland) or $\mathbb{R}$. For $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, the map $BG^\delta\to BG$ fails to be a homotopy equivalence because the fundamental groups are non-isomorphic.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt I should have been more precise, and have said `looks like Milnor conjecure' rather that `is Milnor conjecture'. Still, the statement made above is much stronger than the original conjecture.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The $p$-completed algebraic $K$-theory of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, i.e., $K(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p; \mathbb{Z}_p)$, is equivalent to its second loop space, up to an issue about path components. This is due to Suslin. The descent to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is more subtle than the descent from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, because the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is much more complicated than that of $\mathbb{R}$. Still, if you reduce to homotopy with $\mathbb{Z}/p$ coefficients, $K(\mathbb{Q}_p; \mathbb{Z}/p)$ is equivalent to its $(2p-2)$-fold loop space, up to the same issue as before. Boekstedt and Madsen proved this using topological cyclic homology. I did the case $p=2$. Later it followed from the proof of the Lichtenbaum-Quillen conjectures by Voevodsky and others.